# mkfifo file permissions not being executed correctly

Tags: c, unix, permissions, named-pipes

The following line in my C program should provided All/Group/Owner read and write permissions

```
mkfifo("/tmp/dumbPipe", 0666)
```

But once I execute the code and check out the permission non of the write bits were set, I end up with

```
prw-r--r--
```

The owners are the same, Is it a problem since I'm creating the pipe in the tmp directory? When I run chmod 666 from the cmd line all the permissions get set correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a no-comments post, just quoting manuals.  Brievity etc.

Quote from man 3 mkfifo:

> It is modified by the process's umask in the usual way: the permissions of the created file are (mode & ~umask).

Quote from man 2 umask

> The  typical  default  value  for  the  process  umask is S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH (octal 022).  In the usual case where the mode argument to
>          open(2) is specified as:
>
> ```
>       S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH
>
>   (octal 0666) when creating a new file, the permissions on the resulting file will be:
>
>       S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH
>
>   (because 0666 & ~022 = 0644; i.e., rw-r--r--).
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Salam,
I know it is to late but for other users I choose to write this comment
Even if you precise 0666 as permission, you should know that there is an another factor that is called " process's file mode creation ", so the question is :

how to change current process file mode creation ?

Answer :  use umask(permission) at beginning of your program - and give 0000 as permission

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

this should help .